# WSO2 : API Manager 1.6.0 on WSO2ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to install API Manager 1.6.0 Feature on wso2esb 4.8.1 .I tried to install using Feature Management,but it is showing dependency problem..

While trying to install using feature management,i am getting the below error

`Your original install request has been modified. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.feature.group-4.2.2 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.module.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.registry.community.features.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.event.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.application.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.mediators.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.sequences.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.application.mgt.synapse.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.mediation.templates.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.relay.server.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.localentry.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.logging.mgt.feature.group-4.2.1 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.2 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.properties.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.service.mgt.server.feature.group-4.2.1 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.event.common.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.task.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.throttle.feature.group-4.2.0 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.rule.mediation.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.core.common.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.core.runtime.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.ui.feature.group-4.2.1 will be ignored because it is already installed. org.wso2.carbon.core.server.feature.group-4.2.0 is already present because other installed software requires it. It will be added to the installed software list. Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1) Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group 4.2.0) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.jar 4.2.2) WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.jar 4.2.1) WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.jar 4.2.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1) To: org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group [4.2.1] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.jar [4.2.0] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Webapp Management Core Feature 4.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.group 4.2.1) To: org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.server.feature.jar [4.2.1]`

Can anyone help me on this please....

Thanks in advance,,,,

Comment: I'm not sure anyone has tried this before. You may post this to dev@ list with detailed errors + logs. http://wso2.com/mail/

Comment: @Isuru How to post this question in the link u shared,, ??

Comment: @Isuru,, Ia m trying to install API Manager 1.6.0 in wso2esb 4.8.1 ,while installing using feature management,ia m getting the error, **Updated in the Question**

Comment: Please subscribe to the mailing list. Instructions are there.

Comment: @Isuru Thanks...sorry,While i am clicking Subscribe,nothing happens!!!

Comment: @Isuru Can you help me on this.. I want to use API manager and ESB fuctionalities together..

Comment: Send a mail to dev-request@wso2.org with subject "Subscribe"